# How to know which field name is of which table in codeigniter php framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have joined 3 tables to get information for my page. I need to have name of products but it gave me name of region. Both tables (wiyo_products and wiyo_regions have same filed name 'name').

This is join table code

```
function products_sorter($region) {
        $this -> db -> select('*');
        $this -> db -> from('wiyo_products');
        $this -> db -> join('wiyo_products_distribution', 'wiyo_products.id = wiyo_products_distribution.product_id');
        $this -> db -> join('wiyo_regions', 'wiyo_regions.id = wiyo_products_distribution.region_id');
        $this->db->where(array('wiyo_regions.slug'=> $region));


        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();

        }

    }
```

I have displayed the rows information in search view

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <?php foreach($products_list as $products_list)
      {
        ?>

        <div class="span3">


            <div class="well">
              <h2><?php echo $products_list->name; ?></h2>

    <p>

        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/resources/wiyo/<?php echo $products_list->image; ?>" width="200" />

    </p>
              <p><span class="label">POPULAR</span></p>
              <?php echo $products_list->description; ?>
              <hr>
              <h3 style="text-align: center;">HK$ <?php echo $products_list->price; ?>/day</h3>
              <hr>

              <p style="text-align: center;"><button class="btn btn-info btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Select plan</a></button>
                </p>


            </div>

        </div>
      <?php
      }
      //for each loop finished
      ?>


    </div>
```

How to specify that $products_list->name is for name field of wiyo_products. I am getting name of wiyo_regions. Helping hands are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change name of db fields to make them unequivocal, for instance product.name -> product.productName, region.name -> region.regionName etc.

Comment: Cannot I display name field of products table only in my view? I know changing db fields and making them unique solves the issue but, now what?

Comment: If you join tables like in your example, mysql will not inform you which table particular field comes from (thats what you've already noticed). So I'm afraid that changing db is the only solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function products_sorter($region) {
        $this -> db -> select('wiyo_products.*');
        $this -> db -> from('wiyo_products');
        $this -> db -> join('wiyo_products_distribution', 'wiyo_products.id = wiyo_products_distribution.product_id');
        $this -> db -> join('wiyo_regions', 'wiyo_regions.id = wiyo_products_distribution.region_id');
        $this->db->where(array('wiyo_regions.slug'=> $region));


        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();

        }

    }
```

Selecting only fields of products table solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, but under condition that only data from 'wiyo_products' is needed. If data from other tables also have to bo used, then this is not a sufficient solution.